# "a && not b" gives syntax error?

Tags: ruby

This line gives me a syntax error:

`if @array.include?('cat') && not @array.include?('dog')`

Any ideas?

Comment: _not working_ in what way? Can you give all three lines of your program and the output you _expected_?

Comment: Looks perfectly valid to me, try printing the contents of your array to see what is actually in there. Also, it helps to write out in english what you want the statement to do. I.e:  I want to go into the if statement when the array has a 'cat' AND the array doesn't have a 'dog'.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Tests would be ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
if @array.include?('cat') && ! @array.include?('dog')
```

`!` and `not` do mostly the same thing but can't quite be used interchangeably.

For the curious:  There is actually some sort of quirk in the ruby parser that makes it unable to interpret expressions like this one, even though they are theoretically parseable and sound.

These can be parsed:

```
not true && true
true && not(true)
```

but these cannot:

```
true && not true
true && not (true)
```

Note that last one is different only in the extra space before `(`!

Comment: The only difference between the two is precedence.

Comment: actually there are some quirks in ruby's parser which bork at expressions like the one given.

Comment: 1.8.7 also can't parse `true && not(true)`. The latter two can be parsed if you put parentheses around the 2nd term, e.g. `true && (not true)`. I guess the precedence of `&&` is so strong it confuses the parser :)